# How to combine list of labels in grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have labels coming from two resources

```
label_values(aws_lambda_info{a="a", b="b"}, a)
```

and

```
label_values(s3{a="a", b="b"}, a)
```

How can I combine these two label sources into one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine label values from 2 different metrics: Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825749/combine-label-values-from-2-different-metrics-grafana)

Answer (score 1):

You must use a query and extract the label values with a regex

I would be something like

```
Query: query_result(aws_lambda_info OR s3)
Regex: /a="([^"]+)"/
```

Have look at [Grafana documentation for Prometheus source](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/), it is rather well written.