# Combine label values from 2 different metrics: Grafana

Tags: label, prometheus, grafana

I have 2 metrics as below

```
namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname="group_name", instance="0.0.0.0:0000", job="process_monitor_master", mode="user"}
namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname="group_name",instance="0.0.0.0:0000",job="process_monitor_k8_nodes",mode="system"}

node_uname_info{domainname="domain",instance="0.0.0.0:0000",job="sandbox_cluster"}
node_uname_info{domainname="domain",instance="0.0.0.0:0000",job="sandbox_master"}
```

I want to fetch the job name and store it inside a variable **job** how can i combine the below two queries

```
label_values(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total,job) 
label_values(node_uname_info, job)
```

Comment: `label_values({__name__=~ "namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total | node_uname_info"}, job)`

I tried this but it's returning None

Answer (score 13):

```
label_values({__name__=~ "namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total|node_uname_info"}, job)
```

No spaces between **metric|metric**

Comment: Is there a way to merge two different labels from two different metrics? So for e.g., one metrics would have label `job` and another would have `service`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need to invoke prometheus [`query_result`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable) method, and apply a regex on it.

```
Query: query_result(node_uname_info OR namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total)

Regex: /.*job="([^"]+)".*/
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete JACK's answer, if you need to add more filters to your query you can add them to de first object of the `label_values` method. This is useful when you have other filters, for example:

```
label_values({__name__=~ "namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total|node_uname_info", groupname="group_name", instance=~"$instance"}, job)
```